# How to get a smooth transition between startpoint and endpoint of a line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, linestring, smoothing, geometry-generator

I have a layer with a few lines. They look very smooth in general, but there is a sharp edge at the start/endpoint of the line. Hot to eliminate that and get the blue dotted result line there?

[image: How to smooth the line to get the smooth(blue) transition?]

Comment: Do you want to alter the geometry, or is this a display issue?

Comment: It's just a display issue.

Comment: try geometry generator and use `smooth($geometry)` - see explanation in the expression editor for more optional settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from geometry generator with expression `smooth($geometry)`, there are different smoothing tools available in QGIS - best filter in the processing toolbox with the search-string smooth. There's a native QGIS tool as well as a SAGA line smoothing tool.

The following screenshot is made with the QGIS tool: red - original line, blue smoothed line. Adapt parameters to tweak results.

[image]